# adding more text boxes for an INSERT method

Tags: c#, mysql

Currently, I ha
    private void btnInsertStudentNumberAdmin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

and this is my m
        MySqlConnection conn = connection();
        conn.Open();
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
        cmd.tAverage", studentInsert);
        prevID(conn, cmd);
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to change the method accept additional parameters

```
public static void insertStudent(string personID, string  studentNumber,string  gradePointAverage , string majorFieldt)
```

Note that you need to give correct type based on column data type you given n database for related parameter. for example if personID is integer in database you should change parameter as `int personID`

change your sql statement with all the parameters

```
INSERT INTO student(personID, studentNumber, gradePointAverage , majorField ) VALUES (@personID, @studentNumber, @gradePointAverage , @majorField)
```

and set the parameter values using

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@personID", personID);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@studentNumber", studentNumber);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gradePointAverage", gradePointAverage );
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@majorField", majorField );
```

you can call above method as below

```
private void btnInsertStudentNumberAdmin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  studentHelperClass.insertStudent(txtInsertStudentNumber.Text, txtstudentNumber.Text, txtgradePointAverage.Text , txtmajorField.Text );
}
```

Comment: wait, how would this work with multiple text boxes? each one for each value?

Comment: I understand all of the above, but where do i put the data to be inserted? it cant all go in the one text box that is on my button click? how to I get it working for each text box for each value?

Comment: hmmmm, it is saying cannot convert `string` to `int` and `The best overloaded method match for 'CollegeUI.studentHelperClass.insertStudent(int, int, int, string)' has some invalid arguments`

Comment: you need to convert textbox text to int value before call the method like `studentHelperClass.insertStudent(int.Parse(txtInsertStudentNumber.Text, .....)`

Comment: Ok, no more errors, but when I try to insert a new record, I crash and it says `Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails....` but thanks for the help